# in Windows Phone 8 I need to know the distance between two locations

Tags: windows-phone-8, gps, windows-phone, maps, here-api

In Windows Phone 8 when i have a longitude and latitude for a specific location, how can i calculate the distance between my device and this specific location.

I need a message box to be shown and say to user that is 2 km between you and this specific point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to calculate the distance, you best use the GeoCoordinate class.
It has a method called GetDistanceTo that will give you the distance from the used GeoCoordinate to a given other GeoCoordinate.

Details on MSDN here [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.device.location.geocoordinate.getdistanceto(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.device.location.geocoordinate.getdistanceto%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

you can get device current location like this:

```
var geolocator = new Geolocator();
Geoposition position = await geolocator.GetGeopositionAsync();
Geocoordinate geoCoordinate1= position.Coordinate;
```

then you can use:

```
geoCoordinate1.GetDistanceTo(geoCoordinate2);
```

where geoCoordinate2 is the one which you have already.